# Django Dropdown POST

Tags: django, forms, post, dropdown

... I'm new in django and I have this problem: When I want to show the data selected on my dropdown, it doesn't work ... this is the code

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="/getdata/">
    <select name="Lista">
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

views.py

def index(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    Lista = request.POST.get('Lista')
    print Lista

    context = {
        Lista: 'Lista'
    }


    return render(request, 'showdata.html', context)
else:
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

getdata.html

```
<form method="post" action="/getdata/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Numero:</td>
            <td><strong>{{ Lista }}</strong></td>
    </table>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^', views.home, name="home"),
    #define the url getdata that we have written inside form
    url(r'^getdata/', views.index),
    # defining the view for root URL
    url(r'^$', views.index),
]
```

when I executed the server i just see the following "Numero: " without any number selected ...

Thanks for your help ...

Comment: Please show your URL patterns. Your form submits to `/getdata/`, but you haven't shown the view for that URL that renders the `getdata.html` template.

Comment: the print works in the terminal ... i can see the POST data, but the browser doesn't show me the data

Comment: I don't use a form ....

Comment: I don't use a getdata.html, maybe i'm wrong but the url: "getdata" calls the index function in my views.py file ... that it calls the showdata.html  ...

Comment: You have `getdata.html` in your question, but it sounds like that is actually `showdata.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the context you are storing the **value** as the key:

```
Lista = request.POST.get('Lista')
print Lista

context = {
    Lista: 'Lista'
}
```

If `Lista` is `50`, then in your template you would be able to access it as `<td><strong>{{ 50 }}</strong></td>`, and the output would be `<td><strong>'Lista'</strong></td>`. But this is probably not what you want.

Instead, assign the key in your view like this:

```
context = {
    'Lista': Lista
}
```